# How to remove part of the strings from a list that contains "\n"?

Tags: python, string, list

I have a list of strings, and I want to remove all texts after the "\n" in that list each row (including "\n"). How can I do that?

I tried to use the partition function, but it doesn't work with the list...

```
my_list =["Today is a good day.\nLet's go outside","I have a cat to feed.\nI need go home now."]
```

Expected result:

```
my_list =['Today is a good day.','I have a cat to feed.']
```

Thanks for all the help

Comment: "a list of strings in a dataframe" - how's it look within dataframe?

Comment: "I have a list of strings" please do not do this. I wish there was a readily available post I could link to explaining to you just how futile and self-defeating this is.

Comment: I showed the list already in my post. Thanks!

Comment: `[item.split('\n')[0] for item in list]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the list you gave:

```
my_list = ['Today is a good day.\nLet\'s go outside', 'I have a cat to feed.\nI need go home now.']
my_list = [item.split('\n')[0] for item in list]
# -> ['Today is a good day.', 'I have a cat to feed.']
```